# Is there a way to split a string on multiple characters in C?

Tags: c, string, split

Is there a way in C to split a string (using `strtok` or any other way) where the delimiter is more than one character in length?  I'm looking for something like this:

```
char a[14] = "Hello,World!";
char *b[2];
b[0] = strtok(a, ", ");
b[1] = strtok(NULL, ", ");
```

I want this to not split the string because there is no space between the comma and the W. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just repeatedly call [`substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/) to find occurrences of your boundary string and split along the results. After you found a result, advance the pointer by the length of the substring and search again.

Comment: It's C if you include `<string.h>`, and it's C++ if you say `std::substr` and include `<cstring>`, though in C++ you wouldn't use naked char pointers for strings.

Comment: @Kerrek: Depends on what you're doing. Naked char pointer pairs work really well for parsing memory mapped text files without needing data copies or allocations. You wrap them up in a nice class, of course.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `char * strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle)` to locate your delimiter string within your string.

```
char a[14] = "Hello,World!";
char b[2] = ", ";
char *start = a;
char *delim;
do {
    delim = strstr(start, b);
    // string between start and delim (or end of string if delim is NULL).
    start = delim + 2; // Use lengthof your b string.
} while (delim);
```

Comment: That won't give you anything before the first delimiter though (including giving you nothing at all in the case of "Hello,World!"

Comment: -1 if strstr returns NULL you will increment NULL; 'char *b[2]=", "' is a mistake, correct is 'char b[]=", ";' or 'const char *b=", ";'

Comment: @user411313: Fixed `char*b[]`, thanks. But I cannot see issue of your first point. `delim` is not incremented, it is left as `NULL`, and will allow exiting the loop. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe? No guarantees that this compiles. ;)

```
char* strstrtok(char *haystack, char *needle) {
    static char *remaining = null;
    char *working;

    if(haystack)
         working = haystack;
    else if(remaining)
         working = remaining;
    else
         return NULL;

    char *result = working;
    if(result = strstr(working, needle))
        remaining = working + strlen(needle) + 1;

    return result;
}
```