# In C, how to match a string in a file which is delimited by some delimeter?

Tags: c

when argument is given through command line to search a string in a file which is delimited by some seperator in a file, what command/code do we use in C ?

```
char searchString[20];
char *src;
f = fopen("passwd", "r");
if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error while opening the file");
    //exit(1);
}
while (fgets(ch, sizeof ch, f)!= NULL)
{
    /*printf("%s\n", ch); */

    for (j = 1, str = ch; ; j++, str= NULL)
    {
         char *token = strtok_r(str, ": ", &saveptr);
         if (token == NULL)
             break;
         //printf("%s---\n---", token);
         //printf("%s",token);
         //printf("%s",strlen(token));

         if (strstr(token, argv[2]) != NULL)
         {
             printf(token);
         }

    }
    //src = strstr(token, argv[2]);
    //printf ("String matched");    



 }


fclose(f);
```

Comment: please write your own code and use it.

Comment: What have you done? Let us see you code.

Comment: updated.. please check

Answer (score 1):

If you're just starting out, you could break this problem down into two steps.

1. Split the contents of the file into pieces each time the delimiter is seen. You could either write a loop that looks at each character of file, and sees if the character matches the delimiter. If it does then you would compare the contents from the start of the file (or the last delimiter found) up to the new delimiter you found (or end of file). As an alternative, you may be able to use the [strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function to split the file contents at the delimiters for you.
2. Look at each item after splitting the file contents at the delimiters. This could just be using `strcmp` or `strncmp` to compare the entries found in the previous step (or tokens found by `strtok`). Using `strncmp` is safer in general since there is not the risk of the program crashing if a user supplied string is not null terminated. `strstr` could also be used if you want to find a matching substring.

Now that you've included your code, it looks like you have a for loop that you do not need. Instead, you could just use a while loop with strtok like this:

```
char *token = strtok (str,": ");
while (token != NULL)
{
    if (strstr(token, argv[2]) != NULL)
    {
        printf(token);
    }
    token = strtok (NULL, ": ");
}
```

However, this code is assuming that you have two delimiters, `:` and . If instead you want to split on a multi-character delimiter of a colon and a space both, you could refer to this other stack overflow question about [splitting a string on multiple characters in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079694/is-there-a-way-to-split-a-string-on-multiple-characters-in-c).

One issue with `strtok` is that it modifies the string that is being parsed. This means if you want the original contents of the string, you will need to save a copy of the string elsewhere. This could be done by using the `strdup` function to create a duplicate of a string. The code to do this would look something like:

```
char *dup = strdup(ch);
```

To spell out how you would add that more clearly to your code, you would do:

```
char* dup;
while (fgets(ch, sizeof ch, f)!= NULL)
{
    dup = strdup(ch);
```

And then in your check using `strstr`, you could call `printf(dup)`.

That, and as @Gangadhar pointed out, you may not need to split at the delimiters (unless what you are searching for contains them, which means nothing would be found if the delimiters are removed). If that is the case just use `strstr` and don't bother with splitting the line at the delimiters, then the string pointed to by `ch` will be unmodified and can just be printed as-is. It's possible the newline character removal isn't necessary in his code, if you use the last newline character at the end of the lines instead of including one in the printf; the only issue with taking that approach would be if a line doesn't end with a newline character.

```
while (fgets(ch, sizeof ch, fp)!=NULL)
{
    if (strstr(ch,argv[2])!= NULL)// check whether argumenttis in line
    {
        printf("%s\n",ch); // if found print line
    }
}
```

If you want to calculate the offset for the start of the current token you are searching from the start of the string, you can use the fact that the characters in the string are stored in consecutive memory addresses. Therefore, you could just subtract the address of the first character in the original string, `&ch[0]`, from the address of the current token you are looking at, `token`. What this might look like as a line of code is:

```
int offset = (int) (token - &ch[0]);
```

Comment: I want the string to be matched and print the whole line of the matched content

Comment: Just fill in the code you already have that uses `strstr` inside the while loop. Are you trying to split on a `:` or a ` `? Or do you only want it split when both of those are together?

Comment: My question is to how do i check if the specific string is there or not ? My split part is working complaete fine

Comment: Your code using strstr should be fine for that. Are there any spaces in the command line argument? If so you may want to pass the argument in double quotes. Otherwise the first word may be in argv[2], the second in argv[3], etc.

Comment: using strstr i am getting only the token which are matched. I want to display the whole line

Comment: Oh, do you mean the entire line including all delimiters and all other tokens? If that's your problem, the original question you asked is way different.

Comment: yes the whole line with delimeter. Sorry for half question posted

Comment: Okay. I've updated my answer to include a possible solution. Basically, using `strtok` modifies the string you give it. If you want the original line, you will need to either re-read that line, or keep copy of the original line around.

Comment: I've edited the answer with a small piece showing where you would place that code.

Comment: Ryan one more Question: Now how can i get the position of the tokens and based on that position i would like to search the string . Pleasde help me out

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you just want the offset for the start of the token relative to the start of the string (ie - 3 characters from the start). I've modified my answer to include a way of doing this by subtracting the address of the first string character, `&ch[0]`, from the address pointed to by `token`. What do you mean by search the string based on a position? You're already searching each token by using `strstr` on each token.

Comment: Eg:
sshd:x:71:65:SSH daemon:/var/lib/sshd:/bin/false
wwwrun:x:30:8:WWW daemon apache:/var/lib/wwwrun:/bin/false
rax:x:1004:100::/home/gajshield/:/bin/bash. After deliming through ":" , i would like to position all the token and based on that postion i would like to search. Suppose my first arumnet is "1", the on the position 1 , if a string match is found i should get the result

Comment: Well you already have the searching each individual token for a match down. I take it by position you mean the token number? So sshd would be 1, x would be 2, 71 would be 3, 65 would be 4, etc. Just have a variable called `count`. When you read a line, set `count = 0`. Then, at the start of your for loop, increment count with `count++`. Then, just modify your condition from `strstr(ch,argv[2])!= NULL` to `strstr(ch,argv[2])!= NULL && count == NUMBER`, where `NUMBER` is the token position you are looking for a match in. If it the NUMBER is given as an argument, use `atoi` to make it an int.

Comment: By the way, if that has answered all of your questions, be sure to vote up the helpful answers and accept the one that best answers your question. I suspect some people who answer these questions have spent more time trying to show someone else how to solve their own problems then it would take to just write the code. Also, don't expect this kind of conversation for future questions; you need to make sure you put in the time/effort to make the question good when you first ask it.

Comment: SO, I want to have  loop over tokens, so that i can get the position of token, and after getting the positoin of tokens, i would search a string within this token. right ? So can you help me out to what should i write in my code and where ? @Ryaan

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to write code for you (a few programming tasks of my own to do). You have the idea though, and it will be good practice going from the idea to working code.