# Setting strtok delimiter to two characters

Tags: c++, debugging, pointers, character

i am using the [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) function whose second parameter is the list of delimiters. I am trying to set my delimiter as comma followed by a space eg : `,(space)` hence i am setting the function as strok(foobar,", ") . This problem with this is that now the delimiter is comma `,` or a space `(space)`.

How do i overcome this problem , i dont mind using the class class also

Comment: Seems like something you could simulate with [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) (if you insist on using C string functions in C++)

Comment: i dont mind using string class

Comment: Consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079694/is-there-a-way-to-split-a-string-on-multiple-characters-in-c

Answer (score 2):

> How do i overcome this problem

By not using `strtok`, which can only be used to tokenize a string with 1-character delimiters, and is ill-advised anyway because of its many pitfalls.

Instead, I think the simplest solution is to simply `std::find` the delimiters you're looking for, and build a collection of tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong tool for the job. It's not a *problem* that the delimiter is a comma *or* a space—that's by design. Use [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard C function strstr that to search the delimiter yourself. 
Take into account that strtok substitutes delimeters by zero character in the source string.