# strsep() function - more characters in delimiter

Tags: c, split, strsep

I am having problems using the `strsep()` function in C. I want to split a string into two parts. The string contains info about the currently playing song, in `ARTIST - TITLE` format, so artist and title are separated by one space, one dash and again one space. I want to separate it by this, " - ". "-" won't work because some artists have a dash in their name.

When I try this code with, for example, "Michel Telo - Ai Se Eu Te Pego":

```
// String is in tmp
while ((token = strsep(&tmp, " - ")) != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", token);
}
```

I get this:

```
[root@runeaudio ~]# ./board
Michel
Telo


Ai
Se
Eu
Te
Pego
```

Instead of this:

```
[root@runeaudio ~]# ./board
Michel Telo
Ai Se Eu Te Pego
```

Seems like `strsep()` is dividing delimiter into 3 characters: " ", "-", " " and using OR between them, but I want it to look for " - " as it is. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The separator argument for `strsep`, just as for `strtok`, is a list of characters that are considered delimiters.

Comment: Use `strstr()` instead and find the occurrance of the exact `" - "`.

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847915/implementing-strtok-whose-delimiter-has-more-than-one-character/29848367#29848367), for example. I'm sure there are more examples of multi-char `strtok`  implementations on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code, demonstrate how you can split the string, it's not very useful because it does nothing with the tokens except for printing them, but you can see how it works and implement a version that does what you need.

```
char string[] = "Michel Telo - Ai Se Eu Te Pego";
char *separator = strstr(string, " - ");
if (separator != NULL)
 {
     separator[0] = '\0';
     printf("%s\n", string);

     separator[0] = ' ';
     printf("%s\n", separator + 3);
 }
```

You can of course use `strdup()` or similar function to create new strings with the contents of the "*tokens*".

This is of course not robust, because nothing can ensure that there wont be an artist with `" - "` in it's name, if it's in the song name however, it's not so bad.

This is a working version, if you don't have `strdup()` on your platform there will surely be an implementation of it with a different name

```
#include <string.h>

void extractArtistAndTitle(char *string, char **artist, char **title)
 {
    char *separator;

    if ((string == NULL) || (artist == NULL) || (title == NULL))
        return;
    separator = strstr(string, " - ");
    if (separator != NULL)
     {
        size_t length;

        length  = separator - string;
        *artist = malloc(1 + length);
        if (*artist != NULL)
        {
            memcpy(*artist, string, length);
           (*artist)[length] = '\0';
        }
        *title = strdup(separator + 3);
     }
 }

int main()
{
    char string[] = "Michel Telo - Ai Se Eu Te Pego";
    char *artist;
    char *title;

    extractArtistAndTitle(string, &artist, &title);
    if (artist != NULL)
        printf("Artist: %s\n", artist);
    if (title != NULL)
        printf("Title : %s\n", title);
    free(artist);
    free(title);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And it has the additional benefit of being portable - Windows has no `strsep` afaik.

Comment: @szczurcio: `strsep()` indeed is not a Standard C function.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works! I know that it's not really robust but so far, there's nothing I can do. I'm using Raspberry Pi as network music player and I'm getting current track info from MPD, which returns song info like this, all in one line in ARTIST - TITLE format and I want to split it to show it on a 2-line LCD display, artist in first line and song name in second line.

Comment: if the malloc fails, then this line: '(*artist)[length] = '\0';' will be modifying a byte at a small offset from zero.  This will cause a seg fault event.   Suggest including all the (*artist) statements within the 'if (NULL == artist)' code block

Comment: @user3629249 what line? why don't you use a user name the one can remember?

Comment: @iharob,  as with many things on these web sites.  (at least *I*) I have not found any explanation of how to change that name from the default.  Usable info would be appreciated.

Comment: @chqrlie,  I'm running ubuntu linux 14.04 and strsep() came with it.  the prototype is in the string.h header file.

Comment: @user3629249 thanks, I didn't notice that, and yes `glibc()` has a `strsep()` it's not **standard** though.

Comment: @iharob, my comment references the next to last code statement in the function: 'extractArtistAndTitle()' posted with this answer

Comment: @iharob,  my fumble fingers.  I meant the code block beginning with: ''if (NULL != artist)''

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code using which you will only get the strings depending on the '-'

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char token[100];
    int i,j=0,flag=0;
    char tmp[]="Michel Telo - Ai Se Eu Te Pego";
    for(i=0;tmp[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if((tmp[i]>='a' && tmp[i]<='z') || (tmp[i]>='A' && tmp[i]<='Z') || (tmp[i]==32 && !isalpha(tmp[i+1])))
        {
            flag=0;
            token[j++]=tmp[i];
            continue;
        }
        else if(flag==0 && tmp[i]=='-')
        {
            token[j]='\0';
            j=0;
            flag=1;
            printf("%s\n",token);
        }
    }
    token[j]='\0';
    printf("%s\n",token);
    return 0;
}
```