# Separating a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, strtok, system-calls

I am trying to separate a string into multiple strings, to make a customized terminal.  So far I have been separating control signals using strtok, however I do not understand how to separate specific instances of a character.  For example:

`string input = "false || echo \"hello world\" | grep hello";`

When trying to strtok this `input` and trying to separate using `|` the output would be:

`false`  , `echo "hello world"`  ,  `grep hello`

Instead, I would like the output to be:

`false || echo "hello world"` , `grep hello`

How can I have strtok treat `|` and `||` differently rather than having it saying they are the same?

Comment: "*How can I have strtok treat | and || differently rather than having it saying they are the same?*" --  This happens because `strtok` considers each character in the second argument to be a delimeter. Also, it does not return an empty string. Related [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847915/implementing-strtok-whose-delimiter-has-more-than-one-character),[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079694/is-there-a-way-to-split-a-string-on-multiple-characters-in-c?lq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> split(string sentence,char delim)
{
    string tempSentence = "";
    tempSentence += delim;
    tempSentence += sentence;
    tempSentence += delim;

     string token;
     vector<string> tokens;
    for (int i=1;i<tempSentence.length()-1;++i)
    {
        if (tempSentence[i] == delim && tempSentence[i-1] != delim && tempSentence[i+1] != delim)
        {
            if (token.length()) tokens.push_back(token);
            token.clear();
        }
        else
        {
            token += tempSentence[i];
        }
    }
    if (token.length()) tokens.push_back(token);

    return tokens;
}

int main() {
    string sentence = "false || echo \"hello world\" | grep hello";
    char delim='|';

    vector<string> tokens = split(sentence,delim);


    for_each(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), [&](string t) {   
        cout << t << endl;
    });

}
```

ugly and long! but works!

Comment: Question how would you change the code in the case the user wanted to separate the string using `||` instead because using your code it would not work since the `char delim` would have to just be one character.
Also thank you because it works perfectly if you are looking for just a single delim.

Comment: That's easily fixed, just replace it with a string. However, using one of multiple possible delimiters is a feature that is not so easy to add.

Answer (score 1):

strtok() is going to scan character by character, without regard to characters before and after what it is looking for.  If you want a smarter scan, you'll need to implement the additional check yourself.

Since strtok just returns a location within the string where a token is found, you'd have to manually check the first character of the token being returned to see if it is also a '|', and then act accordingly.

A better solution would be to look into the use of a regular expression here.  It sounds like the symbol you want to split on is not just a |, but rather a | surrounded by spaces -- ie, you are actually searching and splitting on a three character symbol (space - pipe - space)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the answer to your question is firstly not to use `strtok()`, which has a multitude of issues, which are even documented in the manpage (at least on Linux).

Secondly, make sure you have tests. Using test-drived development is a must for these tasks, because here several simple things could interact badly with each other and fixing a bug in one place can cause issues in another.

Further, there are tools (e.g. various YACC-variants and similar generators) that allow you to specify an abstract syntax and then turn this definition into C++ code. I'd suggest these for any non-trivial task.

Lastly, if you're only doing this for fun and learning, writing a loop or a set of functions for extracting various tokens from a string is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input = "false || echo \"hello world\" | grep hello";

    string::iterator itr;

    itr = input.begin();

    do {
        itr = search_n(itr, input.end(), 1, '|');

        if (itr < input.end() - 1)
        {
            if (*(itr + 1) == '|')
            {
                itr = itr + 2;
                continue;
            }
        }        

        if (itr < input.end())
        {
                *itr = ',';
                itr ++;
        }

    } while (itr < input.end());

    cout << input << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*A fairly simply and straightforward solution that seems to solve your question.*

> The std::string::find() searches the string for the first occurrence
>   of the sequence specified by its arguments (in this case the string 'delimiter'). When pos is specified, the
>   search only includes characters at or after position pos.

**Edited**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
        std::string s = "false || echo \"hello world\" | grep hello";
        std::string delimiter = "|";

        size_t pos = 0, pos1 = 0, flag = 0;
        std::string token, token1;
        while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
            pos1 = s.find(delimiter, pos + delimiter.length());
            while (pos1 == pos+1){
                pos = pos1;
                pos1 = s.find(delimiter, pos + delimiter.length());
                flag = 1;
            }
            if (flag) {
                token = s.substr(0, pos1);
                std::cout << token << std::endl;
                if (pos1 > s.length())
                    exit(0);
                s.erase(0, pos1 + delimiter.length());
            }
            else{
                token = s.substr(0, pos);
                std::cout << token << std::endl;
                s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
            }

        }
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

**OUTPUT** :

false || echo "hello world"

grep hello

Comment: This code does not work in the case of 

`echo "hello world" | grep hello | grep world`

the output should be expected to be:

`echo "hello world"`
`grep hello`
`grep world`

rather it is: 

`echo "hello world" | grep hello`
`grep world`